# Why do Get and Filter give different results? (Django)

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I am developing an app where students can evaluate their teachers. I have several models, but the important ones for this question are these:

```
class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='professors')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    professors = models.ManyToManyField(Professor, related_name='students',through='Studentprofesor' )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Studentprofesor(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    professor =  models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

As far as I knew the main difference between `get` and `filter` was that I couldn't use `get` when there were several objects with the features I was looking for. But apart from that, they worked in a similar way. `get` for a single object, `filter` for several objects.

However, in this case I get different results when I run `get` and `filter`.

if I use `get`:

```
Student.objects.get(name="Mike").professors.all()
```

I obtain:

```
<QuerySet [<Professor: Tom>, <Professor: Jenn>]>
```

But if I use `filter`:

```
Student.objects.filter(name="Mike").professors.all()
```

I obtain:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'professors'
```

it's as if filter is not able to follow the manytomany relationship between the objects.

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Because there are multiple. `.get(..)` fetches a *single* entity *immediately*, whereas filter does not filter, unless you force to do a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are huge differences between [**`.get(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) and [**`.filter(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter). In short: `.get(..)` obtains a single model instance that satisfies the given conditions whereas `.filter(..)` filters the queryset and produces a queryset that conceptually contains model instance**s** (!) that satisfy the given conditions.

## Django's `.get(..)`

`.get` means that you aim to retrieve *exactly one* instance. So that means that if you write:

```
Model.objects.get(..)
```

the result is a `Model` instance (given there is such instance). As a result we can thus obtain attributes (like `.professors`, etc.) from that single entity. We have guarantees if the call succeeds that: (1) there are no multiple objects for which the filter criteria hold; and (2) there is at least one element for which the filter criteria hold. So the output is *always* a model instance, not a `None` or a `QuerySet`.

The `.get(..)` function is evaluated *eagerly*: we immediately perform a query to the database. In case the database returns no entries, or two or more, the [**`Model.DoesNotExist`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) and [**`MultipleObjectsReturned`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) exceptions are respectively risen.

> **Note**: since `.get(..)` acts eagerly, adding filters, etc. at the right of `.get(..)` has no use (well unless you define a `filter` function on that instance, but that is not a good idea either). You can however use functions like `.values()`, `values_list`, `prefetch_related`, etc. on the left side to change the type of output (and prefetch certain parts). For example:
>
> ```
> Student.objects.values().get(name='Mike')
> ```
>
> will result in a dictionary containing the values of that instance.

## Django's `.filter(..)`

Filter on the other hand *filters* a queryset. That means that it is possible that after we filter, the queryset no longer contains any instances (if the filter is too restrictive) or two ore more (if the filter is too weak to pin to a single entry).

Django does *not* evaluate such `.filter(..)` *eagerly*. This means that by default Django will *not* make a query to the database to retrieve entries. Only if you call for example `len(..)` over the resulting queryset, or you iterate over it, Django will first perform a database query and then handle the corresponding result.

Since the result of a `.filter(..)` is another `QuerySet`, we can chain operations together. For example, we can call an extra `.filter(..)` or `.exclude(..)`, `values_list(..)` or any other function supported by the `QuerySet`.

Since the result is not a model instance, we can not call the attributes of a model instance. What should be the outcome of a `Student.objects.filter(..).name` in case no student matches the criteria? Or what if there are multiple `Student`s that match the given constraint?

We can however obtain the list of `Professor`s that teach one or more `Student`s with the name `'Mike'` with:

```
# professors with a student called Mike
Professors.objects.filter(students__name="Mike")
```

A filter will never raise an [**`Model.DoesNotExist`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) or a [**`MultipleObjectsReturned`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) exception, since it is perfectly allowed to work with empty `QuerySet`s, or `QuerySet`s with multiple items.

Comment: is there any way to explore the elements of the model instance I retrieved with get()? i.e. the equivalent of values() when using filter()

Comment: @Ale: yes you can put `.values(..)` earlier in the chain, in that case you obtain a single dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Bacause `filter()` returns queryset (multiple students). But `professors` is attribute of single student instance. You can use `first()` with `filter()` to get single object:

```
Student.objects.filter(name="Mike").first().professors.all()
```